# Normal map baking (cycles) edges and bleeding edges

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, normals, baking

I am trying to bake a normal map from a few high poly objects down to a lp base object for a game engine. I am using cycles with a baking cage but am getting odd results as you can see in the image below. The round nobs in the middle have weird bleeding edges and the horizontal panels in the middle have jagged edges.

I have attached the blend file

How to get rid of those?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are put there on purpose to prevent artifacts around UV seams.

If you really want to get rid of them, set the *margin* to 0:

[image]

Comment: turns out it was a combo of the margin as well as the fact that the UV island were too small... I changed the layout and unwrapped again and that was it.